# Are campsites always free on Canary Islands?

Tags: camping, canary-islands, gran-canaria

A few years ago I was on Gran Canaria and I was sleeping in a campsite, which was (I believe) run by the local government. It was super good quality and totally free and not crowded (it was April).

So are campsites always free on Canary Islands? Why? And what about the rest of the islands, is it the same?

Answer (score 2):

Three ways to camp there:

- wild camping. Banned on some islands, but on Gran Canaria you can do it with a permit for up to 24 hours in each place.
- private campsites. These cost, and are limited.
- the state run campsites. These are what you're thinking about - and are always free, but you do need a permit.

Sources:
 - [Camping in the Canary Islands](http://urbanescapists.com/camping-in-the-canary-islands/)
 - [Camping on Gran Canaria](https://www.theguardian.com/travel/2009/dec/05/camping-on-gran-canaria)